# RestAssured XmlPath array

Tags: java, xml, rest-assured

I'm using RestAssured to test a few SOAP services. And I want to verify parts of the XML response, but I have problems to do that for an array. I want to verify, that there are 3 "*code*" fields in the response with value 0.

XML Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="...">
  <soap:Body>
    <Response xmlns="...">
      <Result xmlns="">
        <code>0</code>
      </Result>
      <Result xmlns="">
        <code>0</code>
      </Result>
      <Result xmlns="">
        <code>0</code>
      </Result>
    </Response>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried this, but I'm getting this [000] instead of this [0, 0, 0]:

```
response.getBody().xmlPath().get("code.list()");
```

I also tried to use Xpath, this works, but it doesn't check the number of *"code"* fields

```
response.then().body(hasXPath("//code[text()=0]"));
```

but when I want to check the count, it's failing (java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.)

```
response.then().body(hasXPath("count(//code[text()=0])=3"));
```

Comment: Perhaps it's `response.getBody().xmlPath().get("count(//code[text()=0])")==3`

Comment: @LMC it's not working, count is returning 1. But thanks. When I tried the xpath in http://xpather.com/ it's working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Rest-Assured framework mainly supports testing REST services. You can find a lot of examples on Internet but they not always it will work for your unique SOAP response body.

From my experience, I suggest you pay attention to [Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate) as it has built-in support for SOAP, and also makes XML manipulation a lot easier.